# Check if one item in listbox was clicked twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, click

Is it possible to check if one item was clicked more than once in an asp Listbox? I am utilizing the onSelectedIndexChanged event...but I need to see if the SAME item was clicked more than once. Is there some sort of event for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `onSelectedIndexChanged`, that means your listbox will post back everytime the user clicks on an option.  If you want to keep track of whether the user clicks on the same option more than once, you could keep a list of previously clicked items and store that in the ViewState.

So long as the data your storing is small, and serializable, that should be fine.

So to keep a running list of values the user has clicked on, something like this should work

```
public List<string> previouslyClickedOptions {
    get {
       if (ViewState["prevClicked"] == null)
           ViewState["prevClicked"] = new List<string>();
       return (List<string>)ViewState["prevClicked"];
    }
}
```

And in your SelectedIndexChanged:

```
string currentlySelected = myLB.SelectedValue;
bool clickedBefore = previouslyClickedOptions.Contains(currentlySelected);
if (!clickedBefore)
   previouslyClickedOptions.Add(currentlySelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Adam, but sprinkled with SessionState.

```
public List<int> previouslyClickedOptions{
    get {
       if (Session["prevClicked"] == null)
           Session["prevClicked"] = new List<int>();
       return (List<int>)Session["prevClicked"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adam is right about automatically posting back on change is an option.  if that is something you are already doing anyway, it makes sense to do that sort of tracking.  the property is actually called AutoPostBack, though, rather than onSelectedIndexChanged, which is an event you can handle when there is a post indicating that the value of the control is different than when it was originally served.

you probably don't want to post back every time there is a click on the control, though.  that's a lot of communication back and forth between the browser and the server.  i'd suggest that if you want to count clicks, you'd be better off doing that with javascript on the client and in that script updating a hidden input in your form with the count that gets posted when the form gets posted for a legitimate reason rather than having it post way more than necessary.

this will save you bandwidth and load on your server and just feels like a better approach.

Comment: well every time someone clicks on two different items in the listbox, it removes them from that listbox and displays them in a separate listbox, "pairing" them together so to speak. Wouldn't I ahve to use postbacks?

Comment: i'd use script for that too.  adding and removing from a list control is not complex on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do this check using javascript or jquery. after all it is just a warning.